# How to unit test if a module is instantiated inside another function, Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a file `my_work.py`. The class `MyModel` is used inside of the class `MyWork`'s `run` method. Suppose the functionality of `MyModel` is well tested by its own dedicated unit-tests. My focus is to test if `MyModel` is used properly inside `MyWork`.

I need to test 2 things:

1. If `MyModel` is instantiated with given arguments.
2. If `MyModel.run` method is called. Because it is a long and expensive process, I have to mock it with fake returns.

Note that, both classes `MyModel` and `MyWork` are defined in the same file `my_work.py`. This is just an example for this post. In my real application, they are defined in different py-files. Not sure if this can make a difference or not.

I have tried myself to write unit-test for it, but I could not make it. Could you please help me? See my test file `test_my_work.py`. Thanks a lot in advance!

This is the file: `my_work.py`.

```
from typing import Tuple


class MyModel:
    def __init__(self, a: float, b: str):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def run(self) -> Tuple[float, float]:
        # some long and expensive calculation.
        return self._a + 1, self._a + 2


class MyWork:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name
        self._res_1: float = 0
        self._res_2: float = 0

    def run(self) -> Tuple[float, float]:
        a = 2.5
        b = self._name
        model = MyModel(a=a, b=b)
        res_1, res_2 = model.run()
        return res_1, res_2
```

And this is the file: `test_my_work.py`.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_work import MyModel, MyWork


class TestMyWork(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(MyModel, 'run', return_value=(3.5, 4.5))
    def test_if_my_model_run_is_called_in_my_work_run(self, mocked_run):
        self._my_work = MyWork(name='XX')
        self._my_work.run()
        mocked_run.assert_called_once()

    @patch.object(MyModel, '__init__')
    def test_if_my_model_is_initiated_in_my_work_run(self, mocked_init):
        self._my_work = MyWork(name='XX')
        self._my_work.run()
        mocked_init.assert_called_once_with(a=2.5, b='XX')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: `def run(self) -> Tuple[float, float]:` What does `->` stand for?

Comment: @GeorgeY it is python type hints. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to rather use the [`patch` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) instead of `patch.object` because `MagicMock` [does not support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magicmock-and-magic-method-support) mocking the `__init__` method.

For the `patch` method, you'll need the "target" path to your class. In this case it will be `'my_work.MyModel'`.

If you patch your model like this:

```py
    @patch('my_work.MyModel')
    def test_if_my_model_is_initiated_in_my_work_run(self, my_model_mock):
        ...
```

Then `my_model_mock` will be a mock of the class `MyModel` and will be replaced with [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock).

`my_model.return_value` will be called when a new instance of `MyModel` is called. The `run` method can then be mocked like this:

```py
        my_model_mock.return_value.run.return_value = (3.5, 4.5)
```

Comment: thanks for your userful answer, it works! I did not know about this `my_model_mock.return_value.run.return_value`.